# How to open another project from a project while doing robotium test in android

Tags: android, automated-tests, robotium

I need to change system language on the process of robotium test.I wrote this code in my test project of target APP and want to open morelocale to change language.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QdvQ.png)

```
Intent launchIntent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale");
getActivity().startActivity(launchIntent);
solo.clickOnText("Custom Locale");
```

Morelocale can be opened but i can not click any view.

> Exception: Text not found

Can anyone help me Or have a better solution to change system language on the test process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by myself.

1.We don't need to open another dependensy project from one project, just need to add the dependensy project as a library into our project.

2.Make the dependensy project as a jar file and add it into our project build path.